# dtype usage when converting list to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am quite confused by `dtype` when creating numpy array. I am creating them from a list of floats. First let me note that is not an issue of printing, becuase I already did: `np.set_printoptions(precision=18)`.

This is a part of my list:

```
In [37]: boundary
Out[37]: 
[['3366307.654296875', '5814192.595703125'],
 ['3366372.2244873046875', '5814350.752685546875'],
 ['3366593.37969970703125', '5814844.73492431640625'],
 ['3367585.4779052734375', '5814429.293701171875'],
 ['3367680.55389404296875', '5814346.618896484375'],
 ....
 [ 3366307.654296875     ,  5814192.595703125     ]]
```

Then I convert it to a numpy array:

```
In [43]: boundary2=np.asarray(boundary, dtype=float)   
In [44]: boundary2
Out[44]: 
array([[ 3366307.654296875     ,  5814192.595703125     ],
       [ 3366372.2244873046875 ,  5814350.752685546875  ],
       [ 3366593.37969970703125,  5814844.73492431640625],
        ....
       [ 3366307.654296875     ,  5814192.595703125     ]])
# the full number of significant digits is preserved. 
# this also works with:
In [45]: boundary2=np.array(boundary, dtype=float)

In [46]: boundary2
Out[46]: 
array([[ 3366307.654296875     ,  5814192.595703125     ],
     [ 3366372.2244873046875 ,  5814350.752685546875  ],
     [ 3366593.37969970703125,  5814844.73492431640625],
     ...
     [ 3366307.654296875     ,  5814192.595703125     ]])

# This also works with dtype=np.float
In [56]: boundary3=np.array(boundary, dtype=np.float)
In [57]: boundary3
Out[57]: 
array([[ 3366307.654296875     ,  5814192.595703125     ],
       [ 3366372.2244873046875 ,  5814350.752685546875  ],
       [ 3366593.37969970703125,  5814844.73492431640625],
       ....
       [ 3366307.654296875     ,  5814192.595703125     ]])
```

Here is why I am confused, if I used `dtype=np.float32` it **seems** like I loosing significant digits:

```
In [58]: boundary4=np.array(boundary, dtype=np.float32)   
In [59]: boundary4
Out[59]: 
array([[ 3366307.75,  5814192.5 ],
       [ 3366372.25,  5814351.  ],
       [ 3366593.5 ,  5814844.5 ],
       [ 3367585.5 ,  5814429.5 ],
       ...
       [ 3366307.75,  5814192.5 ]], dtype=float32)
```

The reason I say **it seems** is because apparently the arrays are the same. I can't see the data directly, but checking with `np.allclose` returns True:

```
In [65]: np.allclose(boundary2, boundary4)
Out[65]: True
```

So, if you read so far, I hope you see why I am confused, and maybe there someone who can answer the following 2 questions:

1. Why is `dtype=float32` "hiding" my data ?
2. Should I be concerned about it or I can safely continue using `dtype=float`?

Comment: Are you aware that `float` means 64-bit float, while `float32` only has half of that precision?

Comment: @larsmans, no I was not aware to that. I have been searching for that in the documentation...

Comment: @larsmans, just found it, thaks to your hint http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All floating point types have limited precision.  The number of significant digits they can store depends on the number of bits in the floating point type.  If you provide `float`, `numpy.float` or `numpy.float64` as `dtype`, 64 bits are used ("double precision"), resulting in about 16 significant decimal digits.  For `numpy.float32`, 32 bits are used ("single precision"), resulting in about 8 significant decimal digits.  So nothing is "hidden", you simply see the effects of limited floating point precision.  `numpy.allclose()` returns `True` because all values are close within the limits of the floating point type you chose.

Comment: thanks, indeed with float64 I get the same reasult at float, and precision is lot. Now, I even found the right documentation: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html